# How to disable/enable connected USB devices without disconnecting them

Tags: keyboard, usb, bluetooth, mouse

I've a LCD that I connect to Windows or MacBook Pro laptop depending on the actual need. The screen connects to laptops via USB-C and has a mouse and a keyboard permanently connected. When working on Mac, I prefer to use Magic Mouse and Magic Keyboard that I connect to MacBook Pro via Bluetooth. However, the ordinary mouse and keyboard also remain active as those are connected to the Mac via USB-C and USB ports in LCD screen. *How can I disable those two devices without physically disconnecting them?*

## Scheme

```
---------------                   --------------
| Macbook Pro |  ---- USB-C------ | LCD Screen |
---------------                   --------------
                                    |     |    |
--------------                      |     |   USB 
| Windows PC |   -----UBS-C----------     |    |
--------------                            |    |____ MOUSE (Desired: Windows only)
                                          |
 (TO MAC)                                 |
 BLUETOOTH KEYBOARD                      USB
 BLUETOOTH MOUSE                          |_________KEYBOARD (Desired:Windows only)
```

Comment: I often have two keyboards connected (one wired, the other wireless) and switch from one to the other on the fly with no issue. Why do you need to disable anything?

Comment: @SolarMike Because I like to stash second keyboard and mouse away when I work on USB keyboard and I want to avoid accidental button press. So I want for the devices to remain physically connected to Mac but inactive.